# Trying to Add Row dynamically but getting error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add row consist of three textbox dynamically on click of button with id=btnASize and on click of button with id=btnASizeR want to add a row consist of four textboxes. and on click of button with id=btnWdDelete want to delete the last row which is generated with textboxes and so on.
The three buttons which is mentioned above are generated dynamically and rows with textboxes which will be generated below existing rows are also created on click of those dynamic buttons.Any idea would be appreciated Refer image[image]

```js
$("#btnASize").click(function () {
    AddRow($("#SizeR").val(), $("#TolMin").val(), $("#TolMax").val());
    $("#SizeR").val("");
    $("#TolMin").val("");
    $("#TolMax").val("");
});
function insertRow(){}
function AddRow(SizeRange, Tolerancemin,Tolerancemax) {
    //Get the reference of the Table's thead element.
    var tBody = $("#WireDimTbl > thead> tr")[0];
    //Add Row.
    row = tBody.insertRow(-1);
    //Add Size cell.
    var cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
    cell.html(SizeR);
    //Add TolMin cell.
    cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
    cell.html(TolMin);
    //Add TolMax cell.
    cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
    cell.html(TolMax);

}
$("#btnWdDelete").click(function () {
    var row = $("#SizeR").closest("tr");
    //Get the reference of the Table.
    var table = $("#WireDimTbl")[1];

    //Delete the Table row using it's Index.
    table.deleteRow(row[1].rowIndex);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td class='text-left'><strong>Standard Sizes & Tolerances</strong></td>
  <td>
    <input type='button' ID='btnASize'  value='AddSize' />
    <input type='button' ID='btnASizeR'  value='AddSizeRange' />
    <input type='button' ID='btnWdDelete'  value='Delete' />
    <table ID='WireDimTbl' class='table table-bordered'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class='text-center'>Size Range (mm)</th>
          <th class='text-center'>Tolerance (-)mm</th>
          <th class='text-center'>Tolerance (+) mm</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr>
        <td class='text-center'>
          <input type='text' ID='SizeR' value='2.00' />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type='text' ID='TolMin' value='1' />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type='text' ID='TolMax' value='1' />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What sort of errors or issues are you getting?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody at row = tBody.insertRow(-1); iam getting error "UncaughtType Error:tbody.insertrow is not a function.

Comment: insertRow is a function of table, not tr.

Comment: From looking at the code, it appears `tbody` is a table row element, so it doesn’t have a `insertRow` method.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody what sholud be appropriate method to achieve this requirement .and how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prepared this sample to fulfill your requirement, although not a complete solution. You have to write some code by yourself. But this will give you a pretty good idea.

```js
$('#btnAdd').click(function() {

  var textboxSize = "<input class='form-control' type='text' class='size  range'>";
  var textboxTolerance = "<input class='form-control' type='text' class='tolerance'>";
  var markup = "<tr><td>" + textboxSize + "</td><td>" + textboxTolerance + "</td></tr>";
  $("#myTable tbody").append(markup);

});
$('#btnDelete').click(function() {

  $("#myTable tbody>tr:last").remove();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input class="btn-primary" id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add Row">
<input class="btn-primary" id="btnDelete" type="button" value="Delete">

<table class="table" id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <th>
      Size Range
    </th>
    <th>
      Tolerance
    </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @H77 how to generate different id for each textbox generated dynamically.

Answer (score -2):

I think there are a few issues with your code.

1. You call `insertRow` on an HTMLTableRowElement. [`insertRow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow) is a `HTMLTableElement` method, so we need to make sure we're calling it on a `HTMLTableElement`, instead of a HTMLTableRowElement. To fix this, we'll select the table. We can then use `insertRow()` on it.
2. You call `$(row.insertCell(-1))` to insert a cell. This is invalid jQuery code. [`insertCell`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell) is a plain JS method for a `HTMLTableRowElement`s, so we need to make sure we're calling it on the appropriate type of element. Specifically, we'll use `row.insertCell()`, instead of `$(row.insertCell(-1))`.
3. The Delete function contains similar errors, but I'll leave that one as is so you can learn by correcting it yourself.

```js
$("#btnASize").click(function() {
  AddRow($("#SizeR").val(), $("#TolMin").val(), $("#TolMax").val());
  $("#SizeR").val("");
  $("#TolMin").val("");
  $("#TolMax").val("");
});

function AddRow(SizeRange, Tolerancemin, Tolerancemax) {
  //Get the reference of the Table's thead element.
  var tBody = $("#WireDimTbl")[0];
  //Add Row.
  row = tBody.insertRow(-1);
  //Add Size cell.
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(-1);
  $(cell1).text(SizeRange);
  //Add TolMin cell.
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(-1);
  $(cell2).text(Tolerancemin);
  //Add TolMax cell.
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(-1);
  $(cell3).text(Tolerancemax);

}
$("#btnWdDelete").click(function() {
  var row = $("#SizeR").closest("tr");
  //Get the reference of the Table.
  var table = $("#WireDimTbl")[1];

  //Delete the Table row using it's Index.
  table.deleteRow(row[1].rowIndex);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td class='text-left'><strong>Standard Sizes & Tolerances</strong></td>
  <td><input type='button' ID='btnASize' value='AddSize' /><input type='button' ID='btnASizeR' value='AddSizeRange' /><input type='button' ID='btnWdDelete' value='Delete' />
    <table id='WireDimTbl' class='table table-bordered'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class='text-center'>Size Range (mm)</th>
          <th class='text-center'>Tolerance (-)mm</th>
          <th class='text-center'>Tolerance (+) mm</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr>
        <td class='text-center'><input type='text' ID='SizeR' value='2.00' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' ID='TolMin' value='1' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' ID='TolMax' value='1' /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like `insertRow` is being called on a jQuery object in the original code.

Comment: Correct, it was being called on a `HTMLTableRow` element.